# PyPolars efficient regex mass matching

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, python-polars

I'm trying to mass match a column against a dictionary of regexes as follows :

```py
import random
import time

col_to_map_possibilities = [str(x) for x in range(100)]
col_to_map_generated = random.choices(col_to_map_possibilities, k=25_000_000)
col_to_match_possibilities = ["xxx", "yyy"]  # larger in my real scenario
col_to_match_generated = random.choices(col_to_match_possibilities, k=25_000_000)

original_lf = pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "col_to_map": col_to_map_generated,
        "col_to_match": col_to_match_generated,
    },
    schema={"col_to_map": pl.Utf8, "col_to_match": pl.Utf8},
)

regexes = {str(x): random.choice(col_to_match_possibilities) for x in range(100)}


def my_actual_solution(lf: pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    return (
        lf.with_columns(pl.col("col_to_map").map_dict(regexes).alias("regex"))
        .with_columns(
            pl.col("col_to_match").str.contains(pl.col("regex")).alias("matched")
        )
        .collect()
    )


t = time.time()
print(my_actual_solution(original_lf))
print(time.time() - t)
```

The above code just works fine but it takes a long time (around 35 seconds on my laptop) to complete.

Is there any chance I can execute that by filtering on `col_to_map` first and then get rid of the temporary use of that `regex` column ?

Comment: It may be worth filing this as a [performance issue on the tracker.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues) Not 100% sure what's happening internally, first guess would be perhaps `.str.contains()` is re-creating a Regex object each time whereas the example only has 2 patterns and they could be cached (similar to the StringCache for strings).

Comment: Passing `literal=True` can improve the performance if `str.contains` method does not need to be matched with regex.

Comment: @dikesh I was just illustrating with those random strings but indeed my real scenario involves regex matching.

Comment: Just to update: I do think the lack of caching was the issue. A regex cache was added in `0.19.4` https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11183 - The original approach now runs in `1.5s` for me (compared to `~30s` previously).

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround using a `when(...).then(...).otherwise(...)` approach that is around 5 to 10 times faster.

I'm confident enough this is the best solution if the list of unique regexes is small.

Here is the complete (messy) code:

```py
import polars as pl
import random
import time


col_to_map_possibilities = [str(x) for x in range(100)]
col_to_map_generated = random.choices(col_to_map_possibilities, k=25_000_000)
col_to_match_possibilities = ["xxx", "yyy"]  # larger in my real scenario
col_to_match_generated = random.choices(col_to_match_possibilities, k=25_000_000)

original_lf = pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "col_to_map": col_to_map_generated,
        "col_to_match": col_to_match_generated,
    },
    schema={"col_to_map": pl.Utf8, "col_to_match": pl.Utf8},
)

regexes = {str(x): random.choice(col_to_match_possibilities) for x in range(100)}


def solution_map_dict(lf: pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    return (
        lf.with_columns(pl.col("col_to_map").map_dict(regexes).alias("regex"))
        .with_columns(
            pl.col("col_to_match").str.contains(pl.col("regex")).alias("matched")
        )
        .collect()
    )


def solution_when_then(lf: pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    chained_when = pl.when(pl.col("col_to_map") == "0").then(
        pl.col("col_to_match").str.contains(regexes["0"])
    )

    for i in range(1, len(regexes)):
        chained_when = chained_when.when(pl.col("col_to_map") == str(i)).then(
            pl.col("col_to_match").str.contains(regexes[str(i)])
        )

    return lf.with_columns(chained_when.otherwise(None).alias("matched")).collect()


def solution_when_then_optimized(lf: pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    regex_grouped_col_to_map = list(
        {
            k: [str(i) for i in range(100) if regexes[str(i)] == k]
            for k in regexes.values()
        }.items()
    )

    chained_when = pl.when(
        pl.col("col_to_map").is_in(regex_grouped_col_to_map[0][1])
    ).then(pl.col("col_to_match").str.contains(regex_grouped_col_to_map[0][0]))

    for i in range(1, len(regex_grouped_col_to_map)):
        chained_when = chained_when.when(
            pl.col("col_to_map").is_in(regex_grouped_col_to_map[i][1])
        ).then(pl.col("col_to_match").str.contains(regex_grouped_col_to_map[i][0]))

    return lf.with_columns(chained_when.otherwise(None).alias("matched")).collect()


t = time.time()
print(solution_map_dict(original_lf))
print("map_dict", time.time() - t) # 34+ seconds


t = time.time()
print(solution_when_then(original_lf))
print("when_then", time.time() - t) # 22+ seconds

t = time.time()
print(solution_when_then_optimized(original_lf))
print("when_then_optimized", time.time() - t) # 2.9 seconds
```